# Hide statusbar after button pressed (iOS)

Tags: ios

I want to hide the statusbar after I pressed a button, and after I pressed another button, I want to make the statusbar unhidden again.

So what do I have to use to hide/unhide the status bar with just a single button press?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774968/under-ios-7-how-do-i-hide-and-show-status-bar-on-the-fly-whenever-i-want-to

Answer (score 1):

To do it manually, you can use this method:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
```

Or you can use the View Controller based status bar appearance.
You have to change your Info.plist file with the option
"View controller-based status bar appearance" = YES

And you have to implement these methods in your ViewControllers

**.h**

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL hideStatusBar;
```

**.m**

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return self.hideStatusBar;
}

- (IBAction)hideStatusBarTrigger {
    self.hideStatusBar = YES;
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}

- (IBAction)showStatusBarTrigger {
    self.hideStatusBar = NO;
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}
```