# Put status bar under view

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here you can see, that the status bar is above the black background. How to put status bar under it? Like you can see the navigation bar is.

[image]

I need to get something like this:
[image]

Comment: Unheilig, it isn't this! I don't have problems with my status bar and navigation bar (Autolayout) I want put black background programmatically above all view including status bar, like notification bar!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is possible if you create new window and add that view to it.
Make a window property in your ViewController as shown below

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIWindow *window;
```

And write below code in **viewDidLoad**

```
self.window =[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
self.window.backgroundColor =[UIColor blueColor];
self.window.alpha =0.5;
UIView *view =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
view.backgroundColor =[UIColor greenColor];
[self.window addSubview:view];
self.window.hidden =NO;
self.window.windowLevel =UIWindowLevelStatusBar; // it works with window level as UIWindowLevelAlert
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
```

This will hide the status bar.

See the whole post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794988/iphone-remove-status-bar-programmatically)

Comment: I don't want to hide it, I just want to put into under the view.

Comment: try this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252053/putting-a-uiview-or-uiwindow-above-statusbar).  Maybe this will work for you.